# “Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 10.0.14393 Version 1607” stuck at boot in qemu/kvm (proxmox)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, boot, windows-10, qemu, proxmox

I have played with different versions of windows 10 inside qemu/kvm (proxmox) and all of them works fine except: "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 10.0.14393 Version 1607". I don't think that the problem is connected with proxmox itself. As I know proxmox is stable and reliable system that use qemu/kvm under the hood. So lets think more about qemu/kvm. However my proxmox detail information below:

```
root@home:~# pveversion -v
proxmox-ve: 5.3-1 (running kernel: 4.15.18-10-pve)
pve-manager: 5.3-8 (running version: 5.3-8/2929af8e)
pve-kernel-4.15: 5.3-1
pve-kernel-4.15.18-10-pve: 4.15.18-32
corosync: 2.4.4-pve1
criu: 2.11.1-1~bpo90
glusterfs-client: 3.8.8-1
ksm-control-daemon: 1.2-2
libjs-extjs: 6.0.1-2
libpve-access-control: 5.1-3
libpve-apiclient-perl: 2.0-5
libpve-common-perl: 5.0-44
libpve-guest-common-perl: 2.0-19
libpve-http-server-perl: 2.0-11
libpve-storage-perl: 5.0-36
libqb0: 1.0.3-1~bpo9
lvm2: 2.02.168-pve6
lxc-pve: 3.1.0-2
lxcfs: 3.0.2-2
novnc-pve: 1.0.0-2
proxmox-widget-toolkit: 1.0-22
pve-cluster: 5.0-33
pve-container: 2.0-33
pve-docs: 5.3-1
pve-edk2-firmware: 1.20181023-1
pve-firewall: 3.0-17
pve-firmware: 2.0-6
pve-ha-manager: 2.0-6
pve-i18n: 1.0-9
pve-libspice-server1: 0.14.1-1
pve-qemu-kvm: 2.12.1-1
pve-xtermjs: 3.10.1-1
qemu-server: 5.0-45
smartmontools: 6.5+svn4324-1
spiceterm: 3.0-5
vncterm: 1.5-3
zfsutils-linux: 0.7.12-pve1~bpo1
```

In any case I have not found any similar thread on proxmox forum, google search, qemu/kvm topics/forums. That's why I post my problem here.

This is clean original msdn iso from microsoft with confirmed hash sums(installed more then 10 times).

Steps to reproduce:

Create VM with next configuration

```
root@home:~# cat /etc/pve/qemu-server/102.conf
bios: ovmf
boot: dcn
bootdisk: scsi0
cores: 8
cpu: host
efidisk0: local-lvm:vm-102-disk-0,size=4M
ide2: iso-backs:iso/MS DaRT 10 Eng x86 x64.iso,media=cdrom,size=600320K
machine: q35
memory: 8192
name: win10-test
net0: virtio=C2:25:D9:DD:F2:4F,bridge=vmbr0
numa: 1
ostype: win10
scsi0: local-lvm:vm-102-disk-1,size=100G
scsi1: external:vm-102-disk-0,size=100G
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=9d455cbf-1fa2-495f-928d-3935ec39c245
sockets: 1
usb0: host=1c4f:0002
usb1: host=09da:9090
vmgenid: 40cd47b6-35c4-47ab-8f9e-ed2acb618fcc
```

2. Install latest virtio drivers (scsi, netkvm, baloon, qemu-fwcfg)
3. Accept disk auto-partitioning (4 partitions will be created for this iso)
4. Wait installations end and reboot the system
5. Boot will stuck at proxmox [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtQir.jpg)

However, I can always boot from toolkit (MS DaRT), to do that I need to manually choose [harddisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDhMr.jpg) from "Use a device" menu.

Once it load [successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng8HF.jpg) there is a chance it will boot again an indefinite number of times. I can't figure out the reason of such behavior.

I have tried to avoid this problem by installing grub. But nothing has changed - I am still able to load system through toolkit and always have a random chance to stuck at default load process.

Event Viewer errors(repeatable):

[Distributed COM Event_id: 10016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH4nD.jpg)

[Eventlog Event_id: 1101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRZk8.jpg)

[Kernel-Power Event_id: 41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQvk8.jpg)

[Eventlog Event_id: 6008](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3BI5.jpg)

[Kernel-Power Event_id: 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qvEe.jpg)

Comment: Original post on stackexchange https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019305/microsoft-windows-10-enterprise-2016-ltsb-10-0-14393-version-1607-fails-on-boo

Comment: Did you try using the `I44X` chipset and/or a mix of `UEFI/BIOS`?

Comment: I can tell you from personal experience that I have booted both Window 10 LTSC and LTSB from KVM on Fedora.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I have to use q35 because of gpu passthrough
Btw I've installed ltsc - it works perfectly. Taking into account that it is almost the same but newer I can say that my problem is gone.
Thank you for suggestion to use ltsc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find w/ GPU PT that only one combination of I44X/Q35 Chipset and/or BIOS/UEFI works. I noticed you are using an outdated version of the "Long Term Service Channel/Branch" of Windows 10, perhaps try the newer v1809 LTSC ISO. They only release a version every ~3Years so I like to use the newest LTSC.

https://www.syslogic.com/eng/blog/2019/02/windows-10-ltsb-is-now-called-windows-10-ltsc-just-a-facelift-or-is-there-more-to-it-95717.shtml

Comment: As I wrote before LTSC works fine.

Comment: Yeah, but this lets the community know an answer has been accepted and the community knows it's resolved. Glad it's working :)